# How to use env on Github pages?

Tags: github, github-pages

we're calling a third-party API on github pages.

right now if you view source of our page you can see the API secret.

How can we use env or a similar solution with github pages to hide the secret from view source?

Answer (score 2):

There is no secure way to store a secret on GitHub Pages.  GitHub Pages is for static sites only.  With a static site, only HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and images are available, and there is no backend.  As a result, you cannot use a static site host for anything where you require secure secret storage.

You'll need to find a different hosting platform and provide a suitable backend that can perform privileged operations for you.